# Julia: Minimise a function with multiple arguments (BFGS)

Tags: optimization, julia

I am trying to minimise a function with multiple arguments with the Optim.jl library, using a BFGS algorithm.

In the GitHub website of the Optim library, I found the following working example:

```
using Optim
rosenbrock(x) = (1.0 - x[1])^2 + 100.0 * (x[2] - x[1]^2)^2
result        = optimize(rosenbrock, zeros(2), BFGS())
```

Let's say that my objective function is:

```
fmin(x, a) = (1.0 - x[1])^a + 100.0 * (x[2] - x[1]^2)^(1-a)
```

How can I pass the additional - constant - argument **a** using **optimize**?

Comment: Both questions relate the usage of Optim.jl. I believe that **result** may have a field containing the inverse Hessian or the Hessian, but I have not found a reference in the documentation. However, if this is confusing I can split the question.

Comment: Ok! Thanks, I didn't know. I am splitting the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way is to pass an anonymous function of one variable which calls your original function with the parameters set.  For example, using a variant of your fmin:

```
julia> fmin(x, a) = (1.0 - x[1])^a + 100.0 * (x[2] - x[1]^2)^(a)
fmin (generic function with 1 method)

julia> r = optimize(x->fmin(x, 2), zeros(2), BFGS());

julia> r.minimizer, r.minimum
([1.0,1.0],5.471432684244042e-17)
```

Alternatively you can make a separate named function of one variable which closes over whatever parameters you like.  There's no equivalent to the `args` in `scipy.optimize.minimize` in Python where you pass the non-varying arguments separately as a tuple, AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: Maybe it should be in the main part of the documentation, but we actually do mention this: http://julianlsolvers.github.io/Optim.jl/stable/user/tipsandtricks/