# Optim.jl: negative inverse Hessian

Tags: optimization, julia

I am using the Optim.jl library to minimise a function in Julia, using a BFGS algorithm. Today, I have asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157332/julia-minimise-a-function-with-multiple-arguments-bfgs/43158269#43158269) about the same library, but to avoid confusion I decided to split it in two.

I would like also to get an estimate of the negative inverse Hessian after the optimisation, for further calculations.

In the GitHub website of the Optim library, I found the following working example:

```
using Optim
rosenbrock(x) = (1.0 - x[1])^2 + 100.0 * (x[2] - x[1]^2)^2
result        = optimize(rosenbrock, zeros(2), BFGS())
```

How can I get the negative inverse Hessian after the optimisation from **result**? Is there any field in it identifying either the Hessian, the Inverse Hessian or the negative inverse Hessian?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the comments. Do you think that it would be more efficient to edit "optimize.jl" so that the function would return also the inverse Hessian? See below for a working example - the edit has been introduced at line 226:

```
 if state.method_string == "BFGS"
         return MultivariateOptimizationResults(state.method_string,
                                                initial_x,
                                                f_increased ? state.x_previous : state.x,
                                                f_increased ? state.f_x_previous : state.f_x,
                                                iteration,
                                                iteration == options.iterations,
                                                x_converged,
                                                options.x_tol,
                                                f_converged,
                                                options.f_tol,
                                                g_converged,
                                                options.g_tol,
                                                f_increased,
                                                tr,
                                                state.f_calls,
                                                state.g_calls,
                                                state.h_calls), state.invH
    else
         return MultivariateOptimizationResults(state.method_string,
                                                 initial_x,
                                                 f_increased ? state.x_previous : state.x,
                                                 f_increased ? state.f_x_previous : state.f_x,
                                                 iteration,
                                                 iteration == options.iterations,
                                                 x_converged,
                                                 options.x_tol,
                                                 f_converged,
                                                 options.f_tol,
                                                 g_converged,
                                                 options.g_tol,
                                                 f_increased,
                                                 tr,
                                                 state.f_calls,
                                                 state.g_calls,
                                                 state.h_calls)
     end
```

Or just:

```
return MultivariateOptimizationResults(state.method_string,
                                        initial_x,
                                        f_increased ? state.x_previous : state.x,
                                        f_increased ? state.f_x_previous : state.f_x,
                                        iteration,
                                        iteration == options.iterations,
                                        x_converged,
                                        options.x_tol,
                                        f_converged,
                                        options.f_tol,
                                        g_converged,
                                        options.g_tol,
                                        f_increased,
                                        tr,
                                        state.f_calls,
                                        state.g_calls,
                                        state.h_calls), state
```

To have full access to "state" after the optimization.

**EDIT 2**

Since this change will be introduced in the new version of the Optim.jl library, there is no need to continue this discussion. For now, the the *extended_trace* and the *after_while!* tricks work. Personally, I prefer the latter, so I will close the discussion giving @Dan Getz the correct answer.

Comment: The suggested change to `optimize.jl` would work, but it is too BFGS specific for `optimize.jl` and doesn't address the natural need to access final optimization state of any optimizer

Comment: What about the last edit? Meaning: giving access to "state" after the optimization.

Comment: This is certainly something I intend to add to Optim. No one should have to edit a file in a package!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another less than optimal approach which works is hooking up to the internal Optim function `after_while!` which is currently doing nothing and using it to pull the the information from the last state.

In Julia code this looks like:

```
julia> using Optim

julia> rosenbrock(x) = (1.0 - x[1])^2 + 100.0 * (x[2] - x[1]^2)^2
rosenbrock (generic function with 1 method)

julia> Optim.after_while!{T}(d, state::Optim.BFGSState{T}, method::BFGS, options)
  = global invH = state.invH

julia> result        = optimize(rosenbrock, zeros(2), BFGS())
Results of Optimization Algorithm
 * Algorithm: BFGS
 * Starting Point: [0.0,0.0]
 * Minimizer: [0.9999999926033423,0.9999999852005353]
 * Minimum: 5.471433e-17
 * Iterations: 16
 * Convergence: true
   * |x - x'| < 1.0e-32: false
   * |f(x) - f(x')| / |f(x)| < 1.0e-32: false
   * |g(x)| < 1.0e-08: true
   * f(x) > f(x'): false
   * Reached Maximum Number of Iterations: false
 * Objective Function Calls: 69
 * Gradient Calls: 69

julia> invH
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.498092  0.996422
 0.996422  1.9983
```

This is unattractive for using a global variable and for depending on defining the `after_while!` before running/compiling `optimize` (but maybe in v0.6 this is already solved).

As @DSM noted in his answer, it is natural to want access to last state of optimizer. If tracing is not the answer maybe this is.

Answer (score 6):

I know of one way, but whether it's worth it as opposed to estimating the inverse Hessian yourself I'm not sure.  If you pass `Optim.Options(store_trace=true, extended_trace=true)`, you can get a record of the optimization path which includes the last ~invH.  For example, after

```
result = optimize(rosenbrock, zeros(2), BFGS(),
                  Optim.Options(store_trace=true, extended_trace=true));
```

we can get

```
julia> result.trace[end]
    16     5.471433e-17     2.333740e-09
 * Current step size: 1.0091356566200325
 * g(x): [2.33374e-9,-1.22984e-9]
 * ~inv(H): [0.498092 0.996422; 0.996422 1.9983]
 * x: [1.0,1.0]


julia> result.trace[end].metadata["~inv(H)"]
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.498092  0.996422
 0.996422  1.9983
```

There are at least two things I don't like about this approach, though:

The first is that turning on `extended_trace=true` seems to force `show_trace=true` -- you'll notice I didn't show the output of the computation!  Feels like a bug.  This can be mitigated (though not removed) by setting `show_every` to something big, or avoided by redirecting the stdout entirely.

The second is that we should probably be able to get access to the last state without storing the whole path, but whether this is actually an issue will depend upon the size of your problem.

Comment: `extended_trace` should be possible to be true without `show_trace` being true. For now your `show_ever` hack will work, but this will be changed.

I do plan on (maybe optionally) returning the whole "MethodState", such that you can reuse it if your optimization is part of a larger iterative process. This would allow one to access stuff like invH, etc.

Comment: @pkofod thanks. I edited the post proposing a similar modification (meaning: returning **state**, in addition to the default output). In this case, it is essential for me to get an estimate of the inverse Hessian, since I would need it for a Metropolis algorithm.

Comment: Can't seem to edit my comment, but I just wanted to clarify that I wasn't saying you could currently do the extended trace without showing it, but I will fix it, because the current behavior doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The current least hacky way to do this in Optim.jl is to do the following.

First, load Optim and OptimTestProblems (to have an example to work off of)

```
julia> using Optim, OptimTestProblems

julia> prob = OptimTestProblems.UnconstrainedProblems.examples["Himmelblau"]
OptimTestProblems.MultivariateProblems.OptimizationProblem{Void,Void,Float64,String,Void}("Himmelblau", OptimTestProblems.MultivariateProblems.UnconstrainedProblems.himmelblau, OptimTestProblems.MultivariateProblems.UnconstrainedProblems.himmelblau_gradient!, nothing, OptimTestProblems.MultivariateProblems.UnconstrainedProblems.himmelblau_hessian!, nothing, [2.0, 2.0], [3.0, 2.0], 0.0, true, true, nothing)
```

Then specify all the parts `optimize` needs and enter them in correct order:

```
julia> x0 = prob.initial_x
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 2.0
 2.0

julia> obj = OnceDifferentiable(prob.f, prob.g!, x0)
NLSolversBase.OnceDifferentiable{Float64,Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1},Val{false}}(OptimTestProblems.MultivariateProblems.UnconstrainedProblems.himmelblau, OptimTestProblems.MultivariateProblems.UnconstrainedProblems.himmelblau_gradient!, NLSolversBase.fg!, 0.0, [NaN, NaN], [NaN, NaN], [NaN, NaN], [0], [0])

julia> m = BFGS()
Optim.BFGS{LineSearches.InitialStatic{Float64},LineSearches.HagerZhang{Float64},Optim.##67#69}(LineSearches.InitialStatic{Float64}
  alpha: Float64 1.0
  scaled: Bool false
, LineSearches.HagerZhang{Float64}
  delta: Float64 0.1
  sigma: Float64 0.9
  alphamax: Float64 Inf
  rho: Float64 5.0
  epsilon: Float64 1.0e-6
  gamma: Float64 0.66
  linesearchmax: Int64 50
  psi3: Float64 0.1
  display: Int64 0
, Optim.#67, Optim.Flat())

julia> options = Optim.Options()
Optim.Options{Float64,Void}(1.0e-32, 1.0e-32, 1.0e-8, 0, 0, 0, false, 0, 1000, false, false, false, 1, nothing, NaN)

julia> bfgsstate = Optim.initial_state(m, options, obj, x0)
Optim.BFGSState{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,2},Float64,Array{Float64,1}}([2.0, 2.0], [6.91751e-310, 6.9175e-310], [-42.0, -18.0], NaN, [6.9175e-310, 0.0], [6.91751e-310, 0.0], [6.91751e-310, 0.0], [1.0 0.0; 0.0 1.0], [6.91751e-310, 0.0], NaN, [6.9175e-310, 6.91751e-310], 1.0, false, LineSearches.LineSearchResults{Float64}(Float64[], Float64[], Float64[], 0))

julia> res = optimize(obj, x0, m, options, bfgsstate)
Results of Optimization Algorithm
 * Algorithm: BFGS
 * Starting Point: [2.0,2.0]
 * Minimizer: [2.9999999999998894,2.000000000000162]
 * Minimum: 5.406316e-25
 * Iterations: 7
 * Convergence: true
   * |x - x'| ≤ 1.0e-32: false 
     |x - x'| = 5.81e-09 
   * |f(x) - f(x')| ≤ 1.0e-32 |f(x)|: false
     |f(x) - f(x')| = 2.93e+09 |f(x)|
   * |g(x)| ≤ 1.0e-08: true 
     |g(x)| = 4.95e-12 
   * Stopped by an increasing objective: false
   * Reached Maximum Number of Iterations: false
 * Objective Calls: 42
 * Gradient Calls: 42
```

Then we can access the the inverse Hessian from the state that was mutated in `optimize`.

```
julia> bfgsstate.invH
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
  0.0160654   -0.00945561
 -0.00945561   0.034967
```

And compare it to the inverse Hessian obtained by calculating the inverse of the actual Hessian.

```
julia> H=similar(bfgsstate.invH)
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 6.91751e-310  6.91751e-310
 6.91751e-310  6.91751e-310

julia> prob.h!(H, Optim.minimizer(res))
34.00000000000832

julia> H
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 74.0  20.0
 20.0  34.0

julia> inv(H)
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
  0.0160681  -0.0094518
 -0.0094518   0.0349716
```

This is similar to the one obtained at the last step of the BFGS run.